# Where to locate engine mounts on Nissan Note 2006 HR15 Engine?

Tags: nissan, motor-mounts

My engine started slightly vibrating when the car is in drive and i am fully braked, and I believe it to be one of the engine mounts. Problem is, I don't know where the left engine mount is. I can locate the top right mount but I can't find the others.

Comment: The probably can only be seen from underneath using a lift.

Comment: It could well be attached to the gearbox...